# How change my worksheet array reference in my macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have the following code that I recorded doing myself in excel.  Basically I want to copy the same formula 
`IF(A1="Facility Variance Report",MID(A2,FIND("_",A2)+1,2)&"-"&TRIM((MID(A2,FIND(":",A2)+2,23)))&"-Var",MID(A2,FIND("_",A2)+1,2)&"-"&TRIM((MID(A2,FIND(":",A2)+2,23)))&"-Inc")`
into every worksheet except the first three.  My question is is there anyway I can shorten the array reference where it starts from the third worksheet than every sheet after that one?  The reason I'm asking is because there's no way for certain that the worksheet names will come the same way everytime.

```
    Sub Macro1()
       Sheets("OH-Knox Community Hospital-Var ").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Position:=xlLast
    Sheets(Array("OH-Knox Community Hospital-Var ", "OH-Knox Community Hospital-Inc" _
        , "WV-Bluefield Regional Medic-Var", "WV-Bluefield Regional Medical C", _
        "FL-Wuesthoff Medical Center-Var", "FL-Wuesthoff Medical Center - R", _
        "NC-Johnston Medical Center-Var", "NC-Johnston Medical Center-Inc", _
        "LA-Ochsner Medical Center --Var", "=MID(A2,FIND(""_"",A2)+1,2)&""-""&I", _
        "WV-Plateau Medical Center --Var", "LTM Income Stat-HM_WV_469593 -", _
        "Facility Varian-HM_NM_15140 - ", "LTM Income Stat-HM_NM_15140 - ", _
        "Facility Varian-HM_NC_469584 -", "LTM Income Stat-HM_NC_469584 -", _
        "Facility Varian-HM_IL_416691 -", "LTM Income Stat-HM_IL_416691 -", _
        "Facility Varian-HM_AR_12253 - ", "LTM Income Stat-HM_AR_12253 - ", _
        "Facility Varian-HM_MS_414655 -", "LTM Income Stat-HM_MS_414655 -", _
        "Facility Varian-HM_AR_12521 - ", "LTM Income Stat-HM_AR_12521 - ", _
        "Facility Varian-HM_MS_475748 -")).Select
    Sheets("OH-Knox Community Hospital-Var ").Activate
    Sheets(Array("LTM Income Stat-HM_MS_475748 -", "Facility Varian-HM_TX_416680 -", _
        "LTM Income Stat-HM_TX_416680 -", "Facility Varian-HM_TX_416690 -", _
        "LTM Income Stat-HM_TX_416690 -", "Facility Varian-HM_TX_469595 -", _
        "LTM Income Stat-HM_TX_469595 -", "Facility Varian-HM_MS_469582 -", _
        "LTM Income Stat-HM_MS_469582 -", "Facility Varian-HM_MS_469586 -", _
        "LTM Income Stat-HM_MS_469586 -", "Facility Varian-HM_OK_416699 -", _
        "LTM Income Stat-HM_OK_416699 -", "Facility Varian-HM_AZ_395470 -", _
        "LTM Income Stat-HM_AZ_395470 -", "Facility Varian-HM_NM_469587 -", _
        "LTM Income Stat-HM_NM_469587 -", "Facility Varian-HM_NM_469588 -", _
        "LTM Income Stat-HM_NM_469588 -", "Facility Varian-HM_NM_469589 -", _
        "LTM Income Stat-HM_NM_469589 -", "Facility Varian-HM_NM_469590 -", _
        "LTM Income Stat-HM_NM_469590 -", "Facility Varian-HM_WA_391716 -", _
        "LTM Income Stat-HM_WA_391716 -")).Select Replace:=False
    Sheets(Array("Facility Varian-HM_WA_391717 -", "LTM Income Stat-HM_WA_391717 -", _
        "Facility Varian-HM_WA_391718 -", "LTM Income Stat-HM_WA_391718 -", _
        "Facility Varian-HM_AZ_469592 -", "LTM Income Stat-HM_AZ_469592 -", _
        "Facility Varian-HM_KY_475745 -", "LTM Income Stat-HM_KY_475745 -", _
        "Facility Varian-HM_NC_470554 -", "LTM Income Stat-HM_NC_470554 -", _
        "Facility Varian-HM_KY_469591 -", "LTM Income Stat-HM_KY_469591 -", _
        "Facility Varian-HM_WV_469583 -", "LTM Income Stat-HM_WV_469583 -", _
        "Facility Varian-HM_SC_182783 -", "LTM Income Stat-HM_SC_182783 -", _
        "Facility Varian-HM_FL_475750 -", "LTM Income Stat-HM_FL_475750 -", _
        "Facility Varian-HM_CO_475749 -", "LTM Income Stat-HM_CO_475749 -", _
        "Facility Varian-HM_CO_475751 -", "LTM Income Stat-HM_CO_475751 -", _
        "Facility Varian-HM_CO_10176 - ", "LTM Income Stat-HM_CO_10176 - ", _
        "Facility Varian-HM_FL_244515 -")).Select Replace:=False
    Sheets(Array("LTM Income Stat-HM_FL_244515 -", "Facility Varian-HM_FL_475746 -", _
        "LTM Income Stat-HM_FL_475746 -", "Facility Varian-HM_LA_39597 - ", _
        "LTM Income Stat-HM_LA_39597 - ", "Facility Varian-HM_LA_161289 -", _
        "LTM Income Stat-HM_LA_161289 -", "Facility Varian-HM_LA_33025 - ", _
        "LTM Income Stat-HM_LA_33025 - ", "Facility Varian-HM_LA_351095 -", _
        "LTM Income Stat-HM_LA_351095 -", "Facility Varian-HM_LA_310198 -", _
        "LTM Income Stat-HM_LA_310198 -", "Facility Varian-HM_LA_217368 -", _
        "LTM Income Stat-HM_LA_217368 -")).Select Replace:=False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    Range("A4:F4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    Range("A4:F4").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(R[-3]C=""Facility Variance Report"",MID(R[-2]C,FIND(""_"",R[-2]C)+1,2)&""-""&TRIM((MID(R[-2]C,FIND("":"",R[-2]C)+2,23)))&""-Var"",MID(R[-2]C,FIND(""_"",R[-2]C)+1,2)&""-""&TRIM((MID(R[-2]C,FIND("":"",R[-2]C)+2,23)))&""-Inc"")"
    Range("A5").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do the trick:

```
Sub insert_formula()

    Dim formula As String

    formula = "=IF(R[-3]C=""Facility Variance Report"",MID(R[-2]C,FIND(""_"",R[-2]C)+1,2)&""-""&TRIM((MID(R[-2]C,FIND("":"",R[-2]C)+2,23)))&""-Var"",MID(R[-2]C,FIND(""_"",R[-2]C)+1,2)&""-""&TRIM((MID(R[-2]C,FIND("":"",R[-2]C)+2,23)))&""-Inc"")"

    For i = 4 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        Worksheets(i).Range("A4").NumberFormat = "General"
        Worksheets(i).Range("A4") = formula
    Next i

End Sub
```

Paste into your vba module and run it.

Comment: I get Run-Time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: Also I want to add the line that changes the cell format to general than insert the formula

Comment: you got run.time error because formula have bad reference to the desired range. In your formula yoy have =IF(A1=...) but A1 could be a cell contained in any sheet. You must to specify sheet name in formula, for example: =If(sheet1!A1...) where sheet1 stands for sheet name

Comment: A1 is for the specific sheet the formula is being copied to.

Comment: Thanks Dani I just added the reference from the recording and it worked!